# I can't get my program to go down a line and I'm using document.write because its in html using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am  new to programing and I am trying to learn how to do JavaScript. The problem in my book says I have to write a program using loops in my html page but they are all on the same line.

This is the program:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
    var sheepCounted = 0;   
    while (sheepCounted < 10) {
        document.write("I have counted " + sheepCounted + " sheep!");
    sheepCounted++;   
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but all it returns is:

```
I have counted 0 sheep!I have counted 1 sheep!I have counted 2 sheep!I have counted 3 sheep!I have counted 4 sheep!I have counted 5 sheep!I have counted 6 sheep!I have counted 7 sheep!I have counted 8 sheep!I have counted 9 sheep!
```

(all on one line)

I'm also having the problem on this code
    
    
        My First proper HTML page

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>My First web page.</p>
    <script>
    var name = "Nick ";
    document.write("Hello, " + name);
    if (name.length > 7) {
      document.write("Wow, you have a REALLY long name!");
    }
        else {
            document.write("Your name isnt very long")
        }
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

please HELP ME!!!!!

Comment: Append `<br>` after `sheep!`. FWIW, `document.write()` is a poor way to output data to a browser window. Bear that in mind for the future.

Comment: You should manipulate the DOM, but that's probably a way off in your programming career. Use `document.write()` for now, but move to better methods when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using `document.write` is not recommended. You should do DOM manipulation. However, since you are new to programming, let's not do that.

All whitespace, that is tabs, newlines and spaces, in HTML is truncated to a single space. In order to actually get a line break on the page, use the tag `<br />`. Alternatively, you can make each text a paragraph, which semantically makes more sense. To do that, just wrap the text in the `<p>` tag like `<p>text</p>`

```
document.write("<p>I have counted " + sheepCounted + " sheep!</p>");
```

This also applies to your second problem. Just wrap the text in <p>text</p>

If you want to use DOM manipulation, do something like the below code. Please note that this is a bit more advanced, and it's OK to use document.write while taking your baby steps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                p.textContent = "I have counted " + i + " sheep!";
                document.body.appendChild(p);
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.  You just need to add a `<br />` element after `"sheep!"` to force a line break:

```
....
<script>
var sheepCounted = 0;   
while (sheepCounted < 10) {
    document.write("I have counted " + sheepCounted + " sheep! <br />");
sheepCounted++;   
}
</script>
...
```

Comment: thank you but do you have a answer for the second code?

Comment: Essentially the same thing.  Just add a `<br />` wherever you want a line break.

Comment: Look at what I did for the first answer, try to understand the concept, and apply that to your second snippet.  I'm not going to do your homework for you :P